# How to restrict column creation for existing tables?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, alter-table, postgresql-9.6

I have a table already created in a schema which has columns `a`, `b`, and `c`.  I want to restrict the user(s) from creating new columns.

How to do this?

I have gone through the manual pages about [`GRANT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-grant.html) and `REVOKE`, but in the manual it is explained only for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT`, etc.

I want to de something like

```
REVOKE ALTER on Table schemaname.tablename  FROM user;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to prevent table modification is to change the ownership to a different role.  Tables can be altered only by the owner and superusers - so change the ownership to a non-superuser.  I find it practical to keep a database ownership role for solely this reason (which might make life easier elsewhere, too, like for example when setting default privileges).